# Showing duplicate column names when using Pandas's read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, excel, csv

When using Pandas's read_excel() function to read in an Excel file into a dataframe, if there are duplicate column names in the Excel file, Pandas will automatically rename the duplicates by appending ".1", ".2" etc to the column names.

Based on my research, there are no way to disable this behavior. Setting "mangle_dupe_cols = False" does not work.

If it's not possible to disable this behavior, I'd like to at least know when the renaming occurs. That is, when there are duplicate columns in the Excel file (or csv), I'd like to be able to detect this beforehand before any processing done. It is risky to depend on Pandas's default behavior of renaming the duplicate columns.

Does Pandas have a way to show you when it has renamed columns upon reading? If no, then please advise a way for me to "manually" check for duplicate columns in an Excel file or csv file.

Thanks